# SQL query with for loop

Tags: php, sql, for-loop

what i wanted is to create attributes depending on the value of $numOfQuestion and $numofChoices;

```
$numOfQuestion = 5;
$numofChoices = 4;

$calculatedchoices = $numOfQuestion * $numofChoices; 

                $sql123 = 
                "CREATE TABLE '" . $course_name . "'(
                    id INT(255) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    course_id INT(255),
                    student_id INT(255),"

                for($i = 1; i <= $numofQuestion; i++){
                    "QH '" . $i . "' VARCHAR(255),"
                }
                for($a = 1; a <= $calculatedchoices; a++){
                    "CH '" . $a . "' VARCHAR(255),"
                }
                    "date_added date NOT NULL,
                    time_added VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
                )";
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql123);
```

erro in the console:
**Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR) in **C:\xampp\htdocs\test\admin\course_add_process.php** on line **66**

Comment: Aren't you missing a ; after you finish assigning a value to sql123?

Comment: You can't put PHP control structures in strings like that. You need to [read up on how strings work](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and learn how to concatenate strings.

Comment: have a look at string concatenation. in your for loops use $sql123 .= "QH ..."

Comment: ``$sql123 = '<your query>';  for($i = 1; i <= $numofQuestion; i++) { $sql123 .= "QH '" . $i . "' VARCHAR(255),"; }`` and so on..

Comment: same error... i added this " );"; after i finish assigning sql123

Comment: You should also read up on normalising tables, if you are creating dynamic tables like this then that may indicate that the design is wrong.

Comment: also use always a $ for your variables-> $i++